# Slf4j implementation for Windows eventlogger

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

We have developed a Java application that uses slf4j + logback-classic to log. One of our customers asks if it would be possible to log to Windows eventlogger.

From what I understand the slf4j-api can have many implementations. They can be "plugged in" by supplying a jar file with that implementation, e.g. slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar  etc. Is there a plugin for making it log to Windows eventlogger? I have searched across the net but I couldn't find it.

Also any other solutions for moving the log to Windows eventlogger would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

SLF4J is just a facade, it doesn't implement any logging mechanisms. What you need to search is how to configure a logging implementation, like for example log4j2, so it logs to the Windows Event Log. There are custom log4j2 appenders that do that. Current Stackoverflow guidelines forbid recommendations but an Internet search of "log4j2 windows event log" should give some answers.